# Android NDK Toolchain cant use ".so.0.6-File"

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

I'm trying to compile an NDK Project. There for i have to use an external .so-File.
It got compiled to the name libpcan.so.0.6 because the makefile is compiling this library is:

```
LDNAME = libpcan.so
SONAME = $(LDNAME).0
TARGET = $(SONAME).6
```

My receivetest.c-File needs functions contained by this libpcan.so.0.6.
The android-toolchain doesnt accept the file-ending ".so.0.6" so i renamed the file so libpcan.so . My Android.mk takes this .so as PREBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY to compile my receivetest.so . The toolchain is working without errors.

When im starting my Android App i getting the error message:

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:    36 could not load needed library 'libpcan.so.0' for 'libreceivetest.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libpcan.so.0' not found)*
```

So my questions: Can i rename the .so file after creating it without causing problems?
Why does the App want to load libpcan.so.0, after renamed the .so.0.6 to .so and this .so works fine in the ndk-toolchain?

Comment: AFAIK, you should be able to rename the library per your convenience.

Comment: Can you post your mk file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android.mk compiling my receivetest.so

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE :=libpcan
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=libpcan.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE :=common
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := common.c
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE :=receivetest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := receivetest.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES:=common 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:=libpcan
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The external Makefile compiling the pcan.so.0.6 is quite long:

```
CC := arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
SRC     = src
INC     = -I. -I../driver
FILES   = $(SRC)/libpcan.c
DBG     = -g
RT      = NO_RT

ifeq ($(RT), XENOMAI)
# Define flags for XENOMAI installation only
#
USB = NO_USB_SUPPORT
PCC = NO_PCCARD_SUPPORT

INC     = -I. -I../driver -I/usr/xenomai/include
SKIN = xeno
RT_DIR          ?= /usr/xenomai
RT_CONFIG       ?= $(RT_DIR)/bin/xeno-config
RT_LIB_DIR      ?= $(shell $(RT_CONFIG) --library-dir) -Wl,-rpath $(shell $(RT_CONFIG) --library-dir)
RT_CFLAGS       ?= $(shell $(RT_CONFIG) --$(SKIN)-cflags)
endif

ifeq ($(RT), RTAI)

# Define flags for RTAI installation only
#
USB = NO_USB_SUPPORT
PCC = NO_PCCARD_SUPPORT

INC     = -I. -I../driver -I/usr/realtime/include

SKIN = lxrt
RT_DIR          ?= /usr/realtime
RT_CONFIG       ?= $(RT_DIR)/bin/rtai-config
RT_LIB_DIR      ?= $(shell $(RT_CONFIG) --library-dir) -Wl,-rpath $(shell $(RT_CONFIG) --library-dir)
RT_CFLAGS       ?= $(shell $(RT_CONFIG) --$(SKIN)-cflags)
endif

ifeq ($(HOSTTYPE),x86_64)
  LIBPATH = /usr/lib64
else
  LIBPATH = /usr/lib
 endif
INCPATH = /usr/include

LDNAME  = libpcan.so
SONAME  = $(LDNAME).0
TARGET  = $(SONAME).6

ifneq ($(RT), NO_RT)
  CFLAGS = -fPIC -shared -O2 -Wall -Wl,-soname,$(SONAME) -lc $(INC) -D$(RT) $(RT_CFLAGS) -L$(RT_LIB_DIR) -lrtdm
else
  CFLAGS = -fPIC -shared -O2 -Wall -Wl,-soname,$(SONAME) -lc $(INC) -D$(RT)
endif

all:    $(TARGET)

 $(TARGET) : $(FILES)
# ln -sf ../driver/pcan.h pcan.h
$(CC) $(FILES) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET)
ln -sf $(TARGET) $(LDNAME)

clean:
rm -f $(SRC)/*~ $(SRC)/*.o *~ *.so.*


install:
mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPATH)
cp $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPATH)/$(TARGET)
ln -sf $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPATH)/$(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPATH)/$(SONAME)
ln -sf $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPATH)/$(SONAME) $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPATH)/$(LDNAME)
mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(INCPATH)
cp libpcan.h $(DESTDIR)$(INCPATH)/libpcan.h
chmod 644 $(DESTDIR)$(INCPATH)/libpcan.h
ifeq ($(DESTDIR),)
/sbin/ldconfig
endif

uninstall:
@-rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPATH)/$(TARGET)
@-rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPATH)/$(SONAME) $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPATH)/$(LDNAME)
@-rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(INCPATH)/libpcan.h
ifeq ($(DESTDIR),)
/sbin/ldconfig
endif
```

Since RT = NO_RT is think only the parts where ifeq NO_RT matter.